# Adding gaps in data for forest plot in metafor

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I'm new to R and working on creating a forest plot with a data set using the `metafor` package's `forest.default` implementation ( I only have the `x`, `ci.ub` and `ci.ub` in the data for the forest plot)

I'm almost done and my plot looks similar to [this](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/plots:forest_plot_with_subgroups), except that my data goes over the black horizontal border on top of the graph. I worked with that, but I have one forest plot always on the same row as that of the horizontal border, and superimposing with a white line also doesn't help as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085784/r-metafor-forest-plot-how-to-omit-empty-top-rows).

My question is this: How do I add gaps to my data set so that the forest plot itself shifts the black border up?[This is the image of the plot currently with the border (currently superimposed with a white line) cutting through my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nKaN.png)

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's a snippet of the code

```
 require(metafor)
  metafor::forest(
    x = as.vector(t(data_set[, forest_plot$mean])),
    xlim = c(min_x_value - 2 * (plot_span), max_x_value), 
    alim = c(min_x_value , max_x_value),
    ci.lb = as.vector(t(data_set[, forest_plot$low])),
    ci.ub = as.vector(t(data_set[, forest_plot$high])),
    col = "darkgoldenrod4",
    ilab = display_data_matrix,
    ilab.pos = 4,
    annotate = FALSE,
    slab = NA,
    ilab.xpos = c(min_x_value - 2 * plot_span, min_x_value - 1.5 * plot_span, min_x_value - 0.75 * plot_span, min_x_value - 0.25 * plot_span),
    rows = row_groupings,
    xlab = paste(measure, ep_type, ep)
  )
  # print("e")
  text(min_x_value - 2* plot_span, subgroup_rows, col = "brown3", pos = 4 , subgroup_titles, cex = 1.2)
  header_line <- dim(data_set)[1] + gaps + 1
  text( c(min_x_value - 2 * plot_span, 
          min_x_value - 1.5 * plot_span,
          min_x_value - 0.75 * plot_span,
          min_x_value - 0.25 * plot_span),
        pos = 4,
        cex = 1.4,
        col = "darkorchid4",
        header_line, c("Trial", "Randomized Treatment", "N Arm", "Time") )

  abline(h=dim(data_set)[1]+1, lwd=2, col="white")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the `ylim` argument. Do the following:

```
sav <- forest(x = [...])
sav
```

(where `[...]` is all the rest of your code). Then see what the default values for `ylim` are. Adjust this by adding 2 to the upper value (since you added two rows for the subgroup headings) and then use `ylim=c(lower,upper)` in your call to `forest()`.

Comment: Thank you professor! You indeed are living proof that statisticians _can_ be pretty friendly and socially adapted!